# Incorporating react redux into django

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, redux

I've built out a basic django application, and I'm looking to incorporate react+redux into the app.  I've come across several react+redux templates like the [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and [redux-webpack-es6-boilerplate](https://github.com/nicksp/redux-webpack-es6-boilerplate):

These are awesome, except they both run node servers.  I'm wondering:

1. Does there exist some sort of a tutorial or template that has the same features (webpack, Hot Module Replacement, linting, testing, abides by [Fractal Project Structure guidelines](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/wiki/Fractal-Project-Structure), etc...) but does not run a node server, so I can just copy it into my django application (I realize I'd have to do a fair bit of configuration to get everything working smoothly).
2. Is it ok to run the webpack server *within* my django application?  (Basically node would be running within django)  Are there any downsides in doing this?

I've tried altering the above two templates, but they are pretty dense and complicated.  Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason to mixing up django and react app. 
I would prever leave them as two independent parts of your application: SPA (react + redux) + API (django)

If you already have django app and just need to add some react pages into, then build react app as static files and place it outside your django project, and configure your reverse proxy server (nginx) to load those new pages as static pages (react).

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it is possible to use React for templating and Django for routing cleanly without an SPA, see: [Reconciling Django and React](https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a).